# Node.js don't see module, unexpected identifier import React from 'react'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

I install template by `express-generator`, i started it, it's ok. After that i add to project packages `admin-bro` and `admin-bro-expressjs`. After install i try `npm start` command, but i get error. I don't understand why it's not run, package React is present in `node_modules`. Code `package.json` you can see below.

```
{
  "name": "my_project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "admin-bro": "^0.8.8",
    "admin-bro-expressjs": "^0.1.7",
    "admin-bro-mongoose": "^0.2.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "debug": "~4.1.1",
    "express": "~4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.16.2",
    "hbs": "~4.0.4",
    "http-errors": "~1.7.2",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1"
  }
}
```

And error in console:

```
PS D:\my_project> npm start

> my_project@0.0.0 start D:\my_project
> node ./bin/www

D:\my_project\node_modules\admin-bro\src\frontend\login-template.js:1
import React from 'react'
       ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:23)
    at Module._compile (D:\my_project\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:99:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (D:\my_project\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\my_project\node_modules\admin-bro\src\admin-bro.js:5:23)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my_project@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my_project@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\vsevo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-06-19T23_28_03_159Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Two issues here. It seems like 'react' is not listed as a dependency, and `import` is a ES6 feature that is currently not in `node.js`. You should use `require()` instead.

Comment: so problem in bad module `admin-bro`? he include in his dependencies react, so npm should download that, but i can't use this module because module is old, and use feature `import` which not supported in `node.js`, right? Sorry for my stupidity, i'm new developer in node

Comment: Oh i see. what about: `import` is a ES6 feature that is currently not in `node.js`. You should use `require()` instead

Comment: AdminBro had an error with windows - just update admin bro, admin-bro-expressjs and admin-bro-mongoose to the latest versions and it will fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're starting Express, you should import like this

```
const react = require('React');
```

If it's on React, do this instead

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

**Edit**

Require with R, not r

By the way, you forgot the, NPM install react